# Use phpbb user database for Wordpress

Tags: users, login, forum

I've got a phpbb forum and recently I've added a Wordpress website to my domain. I want my phpbb users to be able to login to my Wordpress page using the same username and password they have on my phpbb forum.

I've tried to get the connection working. But I can't. So does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: _What_ have you tried?

Comment: Is it the phpbb session you're wanting too or just the credentials to create a WordPress session? It may be worth asking as a precursor question "how do I replace the WordPress authentication with my own code?"

Comment: I've been searching on the internet looking for a solution but all I found was using the Wordpress database for phpbb. But when I do that my users will have to register again and lose their current usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying the [WP-United](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-united/) plugin? It seems to do what you want:

> **User integration:** including single sign-on, synchronised profiles and
>   avatars, and user management. Works with external registration modules
>   such as social login plugins. Users in phpBB get accounts in WordPress
>   and vice versa. Completely controllable and customisable by setting
>   permissions for who can integrate and at what level, using a unique
>   drag-and-drop interface.

From its reviews:

> Thankfully this plugin lets me synchronise phpBB accounts with
>   WordPress so that users that register on my forum can make use of the
>   aforementioned WordPress features without having to make a separate
>   account for that.

Here are a couple other plugins that might be worth a look, too:

- [phpBB Unified Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/phpbb-unified-login/)
- [PHPBB Single Sign On](http://wordpress.org/plugins/phpbb-single-sign-on/)

Tip for the future: [This page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/) is your best friend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ATM I'm on the road but as soon as I'm home I'll give it a shot. As for now. +1

Comment: After 3 month of trying things it's finally working. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of service. =)

Answer (score 0):

these two are very different CMS so you will have to do it via API, Just create an api which will sync your phbb user data with wordpress database and will create same user in the wordpress too, also you will have to make another APi which you will use to update password and other detail which users will be updating in their wordpress or PHPbb profile.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Actually this is just reformulating the question. Could you add some more details and concrete things (code) that need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used Buddypress as a intermediary between phpbb and wordpress. Although that is usually with a site that requires buddypress functionality.